# Ebpf:undefined symbol for helpers

Tags: c++, linux, ebpf

I run an up to date debian testing (with kernel 4.19).

Helpers are not found on my system (but they exist in the header, Qt jumps to them)

```
#include "bpf/bpf.h"

int main (){
        int r = bpf_create_map(BPF_MAP_TYPE_ARRAY,1,1,1,0);
        return 0;
}
```

Compilation results in

```
undefined reference to `bpf_create_map(bpf_map_type, int, int, int, unsigned int)'
```

compiled with

```
g++ -c -pipe -g -std=gnu++1z -Wall -W -fPIC -DQT_QML_DEBUG -I. -I../../Qt/5.13.0/gcc_64/mkspecs/linux-g++ -o main.o main.cpp
g++ -lbpf -o server main.o
```

Same result with

```
g++ main.cpp -lbpf -o out
```

I have the libbpf-dev installed as well and i have the associated libraries (a and so).

What is wrong?

### Update

even the following code won't work

```
#include <linux/bpf.h>

int main (){

        //int r = bpf_create_map(BPF_MAP_TYPE_ARRAY,1,1,1,0);
        bpf_attr attr = {};
        attr.map_type    = BPF_MAP_TYPE_ARRAY;
        attr.key_size    = 1;
        attr.value_size  = 1;
        attr.max_entries = 1;

        bpf(BPF_MAP_CREATE, &attr, sizeof(attr));
        return 0;
}
```

results in

```
error: 'bpf' was not declared in this scope
```

### Update2:

BTW, key size is mandated to be 4 and not 1; but it is a point aside, that was unrelated to my problem here.

Comment: Are you sure `bpf_create_map` is part of the helpers? Because I can't find it in the man page.

Comment: With GCC and the standard Linux linker, the order you have your object files and libraries on the command-line when linking matters. If object file `A.o` depends on library `B`, then `A.o` must come *before* the library `B`. So the last command you show should work ***if*** the function actually exists in that library.

Comment: Besides, reading [the BPF manual page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/bpf.2.html) it doesn't mention anything about a library to link with, or the header file you include.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Namespace issue due to compiling in C++, you probably want:

```c
extern "C" {
#include "bpf/bpf.h"
}

int main()...
```

Regarding your second error (`error: 'bpf' was not declared in this scope`), this is not directly related to libbpf, this is because there is no function simply called `bpf()` to actually perform the syscall. Instead you have to use the syscall number. For example, libbpf defines the following:

```c
static inline int sys_bpf(enum bpf_cmd cmd, union bpf_attr *attr,
                          unsigned int size)
{
    return syscall(__NR_bpf, cmd, attr, size);
}
```

... and uses `sys_bpf()` after that, the same way you try to call `bpf()` in your sample.

For the record, “BPF helpers” often designates BPF functions that you call from within a BPF program, which is not the case here. Hence some confusion in the comments, I believe.

Comment: Ah you were right, adding extern C{] solved the problem. My first code compiles fine now.